# I am using Oauth for google authentication and getting client-id and client_secret but it is showing undefined

Tags: node.js

In hyper it's showing error someone help for this type error i am using node.js :

$ nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
undefined
undefinedC:\Users\sunny\desktop\secretsstartingcode\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:86
if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
^
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (C:\Users\sunny\desktop\secretsstartingcode\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:86:34)
at new Strategy (C:\Users\sunny\desktop\secretsstartingcode\node_modules\passport-google-oauth20\lib\strategy.js:52:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\sunny\desktop\secretsstartingcode\app.js:70:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Hi  and welcome to SO. Sure we'll help you out, but do keep in mind that we can help you with your code. We expect you to make an attempt and show us what you've made

Comment: In google authentication, if i console client_id and client_secret then it's showing undefined, then how can i fix this error